# Discord bot needs an "Array"?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm new to JavaScript and I'm wondering how I would blacklist multiple words in one line of code?

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content === "test, test2, test3")}
        message.delete()
```

But the bot will only delete all of those keywords together and not separately. I heard that I need an Array but how would I do this?

Comment: Tutorial about arrays in JavaScript: https://javascript.info/array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if( ["test", "test2", "test3"].includes(message.content) ){
        message.delete()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is checking if the string of combined bad words string(s) contains all of `message.content`. Isn't the OP asking to check if instead `message.content` contains the bad words string(s)? For example if the `message.content` was `'foo bar test, test2, test3 bar foo'`, as in containing the bad words, this would not delete the message.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yeah, you're right. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, it looks like you are trying to edit `message.content` to remove bad words. You can use an array of bad words in combination with something like `Array.prototype.reduce` and `RegExp` to remove each bad word from `message.content` and use `message.edit` to replace the message with the "clean" version:

```
const badWords = ['test2', 'test4'];

client.on('message', message => {
  // Create a message with all bad words replaced with empty string
  const clean = badWords.reduce((acc, badWord) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${badWord}\\b`, 'ig');
    return acc.replace(regex, '');
  }, message.content);
  // Edit the message to be the clean version
  messsage.edit(clean);
}
```

```js
const badWords = ['TeSt2', 'bass'];

const message = {
  content: 'foo bar bass TeSt2 baz bigbass test4'
};

// Check if bad words are contained in string
const shouldDelete = badWords.some(badWord => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(badWord))
console.log(shouldDelete);

// Remove bad word exact matches
const clean = badWords.reduce((acc, badWord) => {
 const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${badWord}\\b`, 'ig');
 return acc.replace(regex, '');
}, message.content)
console.log(clean);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: @Myles124 great to hear. Be sure to mark the answer if helped resolve your issue. Happy coding!

Comment: Oh actually, I am wondering if I can make it so it doesn't delete words that include the key words but just the delete the keys words themselves. Does that make sense? I want lets say "ass" to be deleted but of course I don't want "class" to be deleted.

Comment: @Myles124 That intention was not clear in your question. I updated the answer to show how at a basic level you can remove each bad word from `message.content` and the replace `message.content` using `message.edit()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.some` method.

**Discord solution**

```js
const blackListWord = ['lol', 'word2']
client.on('message', message => {
        
    let isBlacklisted = blackListWord.some(checkInclude)
    if (isBlacklisted) {
        message.delete()
    }
});

function checkInclude(element, index, array) {
    return message.content.toUpperCase().includes(element.toUpperCase());
}
```

**Online snippet**

```js
      const message = {
       content: 'word1 is gonna word2'
  }
    const blackListWord = ['lol', 'word2']
  
  let isBlacklisted = blackListWord.some(checkInclude)
  console.log(isBlacklisted)
  
function checkInclude(element, index, array) {
  return message.content.toUpperCase().includes(element.toUpperCase());
}
```